# Wierd Error React Bootstrap Jquery -- V[g].exe is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

My app was working perfectly until recently I used Object.prototype to attach a method to the prototype object, I have since been getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: V[g].exec is not a function
    at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at ga.compile (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.handlers (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.simulate (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.c (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

I have since reversed what I did i.e removing the Object.prototype method creator thing but the error is yet to go away, what could be the issue?

And my modals do not work too