# TypeError: V[a].exec with JS

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this code js retrun erro in console

edited added full code

```js
let now = new Date();
// we need a function that makes hours and minutes a two digit number
Object.prototype.twoDigits = function() {
  return ("0" + this).slice(-2);
}


// compile the current hour and minutes in the format 09:35
timeOfDay = now.getHours().twoDigits() + ':' + now.getMinutes().twoDigits();

// test if timeOfDay is within a given time frame
if ('05:01' <= timeOfDay && timeOfDay <= '23:59') {
  document.getElementById('skryj').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: V[a].exec is not a function
```

How to fix dont much understand JS thanks.

Comment: None of `V`, `a` or `exec` appear in the code you've provided. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. (Note that modifying the prototype of built-ins is generally **not** recommended).

Comment: @Quentin edited

Comment: I've converted your code to a live demo. It gives a **different error** to one you are asking about, and it should be obvious why `now` isn't defined. (You've done nothing to define it).

Comment: oh sorry i try add i have on footer in page

Comment: you should not patch `Object.prototype`

Comment: Re edit: And that's **another** error which isn't the one you are asking about.

Comment: @DanielA.White how ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolve problem like this

```
let now = new Date();

// Utility function to format digits with leading zeros
function twoDigits(value) {
  return value.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

// Compile the current hour and minutes in the 09:35
let hours = twoDigits(now.getHours());
let minutes = twoDigits(now.getMinutes());
 timeOfDay = hours + ':' + minutes;

// Test if timeOfDay is within a given time frame
if ('05:01' <= timeOfDay && timeOfDay <= '23:59') {
  document.getElementById('skryj').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, but to add to [DanielA.White's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460946/typeerror-va-exec-with-js/77461292#comment136560020_77460946) above: `Object.prototype` is being patched here with the `twoDigits()` function, so that every object gets that function - because of the inheritance in Javascript.

`window.twoDigits()` returns `w]` (from the string `[object Window]`) after patching for example.

The biggest problem it seems is that `for ... each`-loops can get broken and lead to hard to find bugs (maybe happened in this case, I got the error when testing in console and trying to post an answer).

Some more explanation: https://websanova.com/posts/extending-javascript-the-right-way and [What are the benefits and dangers of adding methods to Object.prototype in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832617/what-are-the-benefits-and-dangers-of-adding-methods-to-object-prototype-in-javas) and a similar issue: [Wierd Error React Bootstrap Jquery -- V[g].exe is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389524/wierd-error-react-bootstrap-jquery-vg-exe-is-not-a-function)

It can be useful but the safest is problably what you did, just making a function (functional programming :). Can lead to hard to find bugs otherwise.

It's possible btw to extend your own objects, or a subset. Only String-objects for example: `String.prototype.twoDigits = function()`

Answer (score -1):

Since it's a date.
Other way is to use `toLocaleString`.

Code;

```
function twoDigits(value) {
 return value.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false });
}
```